# Layered Navigation on Custom Product Collection Page

Tags: collection, layered-navigation, magento-2.1.7

I am developing module "`Shop By Brand`". So on the Brand details page it's displaying Brand details with Product Collection related to brand. All things are working except "**Layered**" navigation.

I have added "**Layered Navigation**" by XML file.

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
    <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Layered Navigation is displaying there with all the filterable options but not working properly. It's displaying filters according to "**Default Category**", not according to current brand.

Please provide some solution or help.

Comment: Did you figured it out? I'm looking for solution too

Comment: Any solution fo this? @FredOroskoDias

Comment: have u add Layered Navigation in your module "Shop By Brand" @Magecode